# Is there Visiting Administrator in academia?

Tags: administration, visiting

I am event manager in our university. I see that academics are very mobile through visiting scholar plans. I wonder if you have every seen mobility of university administrators?

I am very interested to go and voluntarily work in the event office of another university to earn new experiences.

Before contacting some universities to see if they have such possibility, I wanted to hear from people here, if it is a feasible and common idea or ridiculous one.

Comment: it should be uncommon but definitely not ridiculous.

Answer (score 6):

The term you might be looking for is **secondment**.

To quote one example university ([Macquarie University policy](http://mq.edu.au/policy/docs/secondment/guideline.html)):

> **Secondment:** an arrangement made with the mutual consent of the
>   supervisor and staff member, where a staff member is released under
>   specific agreed arrangements to work in another area within the
>   University or with another organisation for a specific period of time.
>
> A secondment arrangement may be made in the following circumstances:
>
> - within the University (internal secondment)
> - to an external organisation (external secondment)
> - from an external organisation (external secondment)

Thus, you may want to search your university for a similar policy.

Answer (score 2):

I have heard of temporary administration positions being created to fill a special need of the university, but I've never really heard them referred to as visiting. This probably more likely to be well received if you have some particular experience or skillset that would be useful to a university.